# Generate a variable equals to 1 if 1 ever observed in panel data

Tags: stata

I have the following data with person ID and whether they have insurance in each year:

```
ID    Year    Insured
1     2001    1
2     2001    0
3     2001    0
1     2002    1
2     2002    1
3     2002    0
1     2003    1
2     2003    0
3     2003    0
```

What I want is to add another column, which equals 1 if a person is ever insured. For example, Person 2 only had insurance in 2002 but it means he has had insurance at some point, so `Ever_Ins` should equal 1 in all years:

```
ID    Year    Insured  Ever_Ins
1     2001    1         1
2     2001    0         1
3     2001    0         0
1     2002    1         1
2     2002    1         1
3     2002    0         0
1     2003    1         1
2     2003    0         1
3     2003    0         0
```

I cannot use `egen Ever_Ins = max(Insured), by (ID)` because `Insured` is not a dummy in the true data. It has values such as 9 for unknown.

Comment: You would be better off recoding 9 as missing. Otherwise you're going to be working around it so long as you have these data to analyse. See help for `recode`. `mvdecode`.

Comment: @NickCox Just did it using `recode Insured 9 = .` Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technique for "any" and "all" problems is documented in [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/). See also [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055) for a more detailed discussion. Here is one way to do it.

```
clear 
input ID    Year    Insured
1     2001    1
2     2001    0
3     2001    0
1     2002    1
2     2002    1
3     2002    0
1     2003    1
2     2003    0
3     2003    0
end 

egen Ever_Ins = max(Insured == 1), by(ID) 
sort ID Year 
list , sepby(ID) 

     +--------------------------------+
     | ID   Year   Insured   Ever_Ins |
     |--------------------------------|
  1. |  1   2001         1          1 |
  2. |  1   2002         1          1 |
  3. |  1   2003         1          1 |
     |--------------------------------|
  4. |  2   2001         0          1 |
  5. |  2   2002         1          1 |
  6. |  2   2003         0          1 |
     |--------------------------------|
  7. |  3   2001         0          0 |
  8. |  3   2002         0          0 |
  9. |  3   2003         0          0 |
     +--------------------------------+
```